# Live Audio Streaming with Vue, Socket.io Web Audio Api

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, audio, socket.io

I'm trying to use the following code for Live Audio Streaming. However I'm totally unable to play the recorded sound back and don't know whether this is the best approach to do that job or not. Could you please help me out. I've tried so many example and just reached out at this point. Here're my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Audio" class="col-2 col-form-label labelTop">Audio</label>
        <div class="col">
          <b-button-group>
              <b-button
                variant="outline-primary"
                @click="recordAudio()"
                id="button_record"
              >
                <b-icon icon="play-fill"></b-icon> Record
              </b-button>


            <b-button
              variant="outline-danger"
              id="button_stop"
              @click="stopRecording()"
            >
              <b-icon icon="stop-fill"></b-icon> Stop
            </b-button>
          </b-button-group>
        </div>
      </div>
  <div class="form-group">
        <audio ref="player" id="audio" controls>
          <source type="audio/webm;codecs=opus" id="mp3Source" />
          Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
      </div>
  </div>
  
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      audioContext: null, //for recorder
      audioC: null, // for receiver
      
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let audioElement = document.getElementById('audio')
    this.audioC = new AudioContext()
    let source = null

    // For nuxt-socket.io 
    this.socket = this.$nuxtSocket({
      channel: '/',
    })
    
    this.socket.on('buffer.received', (msg, cb) => {
      
      audioChunkReceived(this.audioC, msg, this.audioC.sampleRate)

      function audioChunkReceived(audioContext, data, sample_rate) {
        const fbu = new Float32Array(data)
        var audioBuffer = audioContext.createBuffer(
          1,
          /*data.length*/ 2048,
          sample_rate
        )
        audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(fbu)
        var source = audioContext.createBufferSource() // creates a sound source
        source.buffer = audioBuffer
        source.connect(audioContext.destination)
        source.start()
        // source.connect(streamNode)
        // audioElement.srcObject = streamNode.stream
      }

      
    })
    
    
  },
  methods: {
    
    recordAudio() {

      let device = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
      let items = []
      device.then((stream) => {
        // keep the context in a global variable
        this.stream = stream
        let socket = this.socket
        this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)

        let bufferSize = 1024 * 16
        let audioContext = new AudioContext()
        this.audioContext = audioContext
        let processor = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1)
        this.processor = processor
        processor.connect(audioContext.destination)
        this.input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
        this.input.connect(processor)
        processor.onaudioprocess = (e) => {
          // receives data from microphone
          const buffer = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0) // get only one audio channel
          socket.emit('micBinaryStream', buffer) // send to server via web socket
        }
        
        this.recorder.start(2000)
      })
    },
    stopRecording() {
      
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

and Server side

```
socket.on("micBinaryStream", (buffer) => {
    io.emit("buffer.received", buffer);
  });
```

Comment: are you streaming audio from server => browser or the other way around? it's not clear - any errors in the browser console? in the server?

Comment: No error found in console. However I'm not hearing any sound in browser. .... Server is only handling the socket.io events as described above (`socket.on("micBinaryStream", (buffer) => {io.emit("buffer.received", buffer);});`)... I want live audio streaming like Facebook, YouTube does but Audio only.

Comment: "live audio streaming" ... so you stream from the source client (a browser) to multiple clients (also browsers) via your server - so, have you determined that the sending part works?

Comment: yes @JaromandaX the sending parts absolutely works. I'm able to send the chunks of data to server at (`processor.onaudioprocess = (e) => {const buffer = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0); socket.emit('micBinaryStream', buffer);}`) and then receive back at (`this.socket.on('buffer.received', (msg, cb) => {audioChunkReceived(this.audioC, msg, this.audioC.sampleRate)`)